# Are CouchDB Views fast?

Tags: couchdb

If I want to get data out quickly from CouchDB is it significantly faster to grab a single doc from it's id, than to grab a view and then just use the appropriate doc in that view?

Comment: The view I'm grabbing will have less than 100 docs in it.

Comment: What kind of "fast" do you mean? 1 req/second below 10ms? Or 100 req/sec each below 500ms?

Comment: Shoot, I don't know. Can you explain your metric? Or provide a link so I can read up on it. Sorry, I'm self-taught and still learning : )

Comment: In the end, the computation of the view will be done, when a single document has changed. This will result in calling map(doc) and if there is a reduce function, it too. Check out the answer by llabball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grabbing a doc by its id uses the built-in view `_all_docs` which is the primary index.

The only difference to secondary indexes as a view you mentioned is that the primary index is always up-to-date - there will never be a time lag for updating the index when the request comes in.

tl;dr Both requests variants compared have no performance differences as long as the indexes are up-to-date. Otherwise the id-lookup in the primary index wins.

Comment: If a stale but faster version of the index is ok, using the &stale=ok or &stale=update_after can be used: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

Comment: Thanks for all the info! A view will work wonderfully for my case. The docs represent team members on the site, and contain the biographical data that makes up each team member's page on the website. So, a performance impact (of probably less than one second) will only be incurred by the first visitor following us adding a new member to our team. This happens a few times in a year.